# HBase schema row key design - increment counter?

Tags: hbase, counter, bigtable

I am struggling to find any documents about increment counter in HBase. Any one knows any?

I am designing a Hbase table schema for my application. My row_key can't guarantee 100% uniqueness. So the question is that when my row_key starts having duplicates, I would like to have an increment counter as part of the row key to distinguish them. thoughts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do one thing just add time stamp with your row key so it will be always unique

as

```
info:aaa#timestamp
info:bbb#timestamp
info:ccc#timestamp
info:aaa#timestamp
info:bbb#timestamp
info:ccc#timestamp
info:aaa#timestamp
info:bbb#timestamp
info:ccc#timestamp
```

os if you do like this the row key will always unique

one more thing you can try

uidgen

It's usually found in /usr/bin/

nyancat ~ # uuidgen
488bc393-a4f5-4a83-8df8-8c15e737dcc5

if you are using java then

```
public class GenerateUUID {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    UUID idOne = UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID idTwo = UUID.randomUUID();
    log("UUID One: " + idOne);
    log("UUID Two: " + idTwo);
  }

  private static void log(Object aObject){
    System.out.println( String.valueOf(aObject) );
  }
}
```

and then you can attach this as your key

Comment: I've added timestamp in the rowkey design, even like that, it might still potentially have duplicates given my data gets generated very quickly.

Comment: Can you add a random number or GUID? Will that solve the uniqueness problem?

Comment: A timestamp is not a reliable unique ID. You can find a good approach to distributed UUID generation in Boundary's [writeup of their Flake project](http://boundary.com/blog/2012/01/12/flake-a-decentralized-k-ordered-unique-id-generator-in-erlang/) (see also Twitter's [Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake)). It has the nice properties of remaining time-ordered while guaranteeing uniqueness.